# Get the name of an object and passing parameters

Tags: vb.net

For example if I have a function call like below

```
  Function callingMe()

  Exit Function
```

and my Function call is like below

```
  SomeObj.callingMe('1','2','3','4','5') // Variable number of arguments
```

Inside callingMe() function, I want to know arguments passed i.e 1,2,3,4,5 and the Object i.e SomeObj in above case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [`ParamArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9z7h91e4.aspx) to accept a variable number of arguments.

*Update according to your question in the comments: To get a reference to the caller you must pass it in as a separate argument. Please note that all fixed parameters must come before the `ParamArray`*

```
Function callingMe(caller As Object, ParamArray parameters() As String)
    For  i as Integer = 0  to parameters.Length -1 
        Console.WriteLine(parameters(i))
    Next i 
End Function

// Method call:
SomeObj.callingMe(Me, "1", "2", "3", ...)
```

Comment: Thanks, And how can I get the reference to object called this Function.

Comment: To get the reference you must pass the calling object as an argument. I'll update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

The method declaration needs to be explicit, to be able to accept n parameters.
In this case, [`ParamArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9z7h91e4.aspx) can be used.

EDIT: The name of the variable cannot be determined, as the name is immaterial to the runtime. You can refer to the instance of the class using `Me` keyword.

EDIT2: Assuming that someObj is an instance of a class `Person`, which has a property named `FirstName`, you could use `Me.FirstName` inside `callingMe` (which is a method in `Person` class).

```
Sub Main
    dim someObj as Person
    someObj = new Person

    someObj.FirstName = "Hello"
    someObj.callingMe("1","2","3")
End Sub

' Define other methods and classes here
Class Person
    Private firstNameValue As String
    Public Property FirstName() As String
        Get
            Return firstNameValue
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As String)
            firstNameValue = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Function callingMe(paramarray args() as string)
        Console.WriteLine(me.FirstName + "," + args(0))
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Could you please provide me an example of "Me"